# меняю картинку this.src - а она меняется только 1 раз помогите решить

Tags: jquery

```
//jshint esversion:6

$(document).ready(function(){

  let i = [
    'catalog/view/theme/default/image/mob_menu.png',
    'catalog/view/theme/default/image/mob_menu_close.png'
  ];

  $('.mob_menu_image').click(function() {
    $('.mob_menu').slideToggle("slow");

    if (this.src=i[0]) {
      this.src=i[1];
    } else { 
      this.src=i[0]
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `this.src=i[0]` это вы устанавливаете значение в src, и у вас if всегда будет  true. В чём задача?

Comment: `if (this.src == i[0]) {`

Comment: когда использую == вообще не меняет не разу img.
задача по клику на изображение + открыть список вниз и изменить изображение на - по следеющему клику закрыть и изображение назад на +

Comment: if (this.src==i[1]) {
 this.src=i[0];
} else { this.src=i[1];
}  поменял местами единицы и 0 - заработала схема с == (но меняет изоброжение только 1 раз!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  let i = [
    'catalog/view/theme/default/image/mob_menu.png',
    'catalog/view/theme/default/image/mob_menu_close.png'
  ];
  let current = 0; // or 1

  $('.mob_menu_image').click(function() {
    $('.mob_menu').slideToggle("slow");
    this.src = i[current = (++current) % i.length];
  });
});
```

Comment: блин почему стеснялся сразу спросить =)
разными способоми пробывал уже день потратил..